# why is $\mathbb{Z}$ an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with no cluster point.

Tags: real-analysis

I have read this fact but I can't figure out why.

I know that in order to have a cluster point, we need to find a point $p$ s.t. an open ball centered at $p$ contains infinitely many points. How come $\mathbb{Z}$ has finitely many integers in the ball?

Comment: Consider the intervals $(n-1/2,n+1/2)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Ian ok I see what you are saying, how do we show that for any finite radius in the ball, there is finitely many integers contained in the ball?

Comment: You don't really need *any* finite radius. You just need *some* finite radius which only contains finitely many integers. And I just gave you one. (Be careful about quantifiers: having a cluster point is a "for all" statement, so its negation is a "there exists" statement.)

Comment: @Ian Thanks you!

Comment: @Ian just for clarification, would a radius of $\frac{1}{n}$ also work? since the only integers in this ball would be 1, -1?

Answer (score 3):

It is because all its points are *isolated*, i.e. a neighbourhood $(n-\varepsilon,n+\varepsilon)$ of an integer $n$, if small enough, contains only that integer. Just talke $\varepsilon<\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a ball has finite radius, so it is an interval of the form $(x-\epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ where $x$ is some real number. Any point $p$ in the ball must satisfy $|p-x| < \epsilon$. Since $|p| - |x| \leq |p-x|$ by the reverse triangle inequality, any point $p$ in the interval must satisfy
$$|p| - |x| < \epsilon$$
or equivalently,
$$|p| < |x| + \epsilon$$
Since $|x| + \epsilon$ is a finite number, this inequality can only be satisfied by finitely many integer values of $p$.